# Is $2$ not irreducible in $\mathbb Z_{8}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

There is a question in the book I am following:

> Prove that in $\mathbb Z_{8}$, $2$ is a prime element but not irreducible, where $\mathbb Z_{8}$ is the ring of integers modulo $8$.

I proved the first part, but I am not able to prove the second part. I think that $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_{8}$. Below is my reasoning:

If $ab=2$ in $\mathbb Z_{8}$, then $ab=8n+2$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$. Clearly there is only one factor of $2$ in $8n+2$. So only one of $a$ and $b$ can be even; other must be an odd number. But odd numbers in $\mathbb Z_{8}$ are units. So $2$ must be irreducible.

Is there a fault in above line of reasoning?

Comment: why do you think that odd numbers are units? E.g. $5*3 = 7$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$

Comment: @user159517 Because for any odd integer $2n+1$, $(2n+1)^2 = 4n^2+4n+1 = 4n(n+1) + 1$. Notice that $n(n+1)$ is always even. So $4n(n+1)$ is divisible by 8. So $(2n+1)^2 = 1 (mod 8)$. Basically, every odd integer in $Z_{8}$ is self inverse.

Comment: @user159517 A [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) is an invertible element.

Comment: Most likely this is a typo: it should be $\mathbb Z_6$.

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly fine, $2$ is indeed irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_8$.